# Can I get() or xcom.pull() a variable in the MAIN part of an Airflow script (outside a PythonOperator)?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a situation where I need to find a specific folder in S3 to pass onto a PythonOperator in an Airflow script. I am doing this using another PythonOperator that finds the correct directory. I can successfully either xcom.push() or Variable.set() and read it back *within* the PythonOperator. The problem is, I need to pass this variable onto a separate PythonOperator that uses code in a python library. Therefore, I need to Variable.get() or xcom.pull() this variable within the main part of the Airflow script. I have searched quite a bit and can't seem to figure out if this is possible or not. Below is some code for reference:

```
    def check_for_done_file(**kwargs):

    ### This function does a bunch of stuff to find the correct S3 path to 
    ### populate target_dir, this has been verified and works

    Variable.set("target_dir", done_file_list.pop())
    test = Variable.get("target_dir")
    print("TEST: ", test)

    #### END OF METHOD, BEGIN MAIN

with my_dag:

   ### CALLING METHOD FROM MAIN, POPULATING VARIABLE

   check_for_done_file_task = PythonOperator(
      task_id = 'check_for_done_file',
      python_callable = check_for_done_file,
      dag = my_dag,
      op_kwargs = {
          "source_bucket" : "my_source_bucket",
          "source_path" : "path/to/the/s3/folder/I/need"
      }
   )

   target_dir = Variable.get("target_dir") # I NEED THIS VAR HERE.

   move_data_to_in_progress_task = PythonOperator(
       task_id = 'move-from-incoming-to-in-progress',
       python_callable = FileOps.move, # <--- PYTHON LIBRARY THAT COPIES FILES FROM SRC TO DEST
       dag = my_dag,
       op_kwargs = {
           "source_bucket" : "source_bucket",
           "source_path" : "path/to/my/s3/folder/" + target_dir,
           "destination_bucket" : "destination_bucket",
           "destination_path" : "path/to/my/s3/folder/" + target_dir,
           "recurse" : True
       }
    )
```

So, is the only way to accomplish this to augment the library to look for the "target_dir" variable? I don't think Airflow main has a context, and therefore what I want to do may not be possible. Any Airflow experts, please weigh in to let me know what my options might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`op_kwargs` is a templated field. So you can use `xcom_push`:

```py
def check_for_done_file(**kwargs):
    ...
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(value=y)
```

and use jinja template in `op_kwargs`:

```py
   move_data_to_in_progress_task = PythonOperator(
       task_id = 'move-from-incoming-to-in-progress',
       python_callable = FileOps.move, # <--- PYTHON LIBRARY THAT COPIES FILES FROM SRC TO DEST
       dag = my_dag,
       op_kwargs = {
           "source_bucket" : "source_bucket",
           "source_path" : "path/to/my/s3/folder/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='check_for_done_file') }}",
           "destination_bucket" : "destination_bucket",
           "destination_path" : "path/to/my/s3/folder/{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='check_for_done_file') }}",
           "recurse" : True
       }
    )
```

Also, add `provide_context=True` to your `check_for_done_file_task` task to pass context dictionary to callables.

Comment: the line kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(value=done_file_list.pop()) - (changed to push my partiulcar value) results in a stack trace:       Subtask check_for_done_file KeyError: 'ti'
[2019-11-11 09:52:26,241] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-11-11 09:52:26,240] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

Comment: add `provide_context=True` to your `check_for_done_file_task` task and try again

Comment: This was very helpful and solved my problem. Thank you. Just for clarification, I needed to return the value in 'check_for_done_file_task', as opposed to doing a xcom.push().

Comment: Oh yes :) You can use xcom just by returning a value or specifying a key. Example: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3fa64ea7a9476de4810f3b95f170074a2b422206/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py#L37-L44